# Calculate the volume of the tetrahedron...

Tags: geometry, volume

**The question**

Let $ABXY$ be a tetrahedron such that the triangles $ABX$ and $ABY$ are isosceles right angle in $A$ with legs of $2$ cm. Calculate the volume of the tetrahedron, knowing that there is a point $P$ such that $PA = PB=PX = PY = \sqrt{5} cm$.

**The drawing**

[image]

**my idea**

$AB=AX=AY=2$ and using Phytagoras theorem we get $BX=BY=2\sqrt{2}$

We can use Chasles Formula to write the volume $$\frac{a*b* dis(a,b)*sin(a,b)}{6}$$ .

The volume of the tetrahedron is also equal to $\frac{2*A(AXY)}{3}$

I don't know where the point $P$ should be put.

I hope one of you can help me solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You don't know the angle $\angle XAY$. That's why you need the distance

Comment: @CalvinLin I think she wanted to say "isosceles right angle triangles"

Comment: @CalvinLin I edited it

Comment: @Andrei What distance and why i need it?

Comment: By $PA=PB=\sqrt{5}$ cm $P$ may rotate on a circle around $AB$, but by $PX=PY=\sqrt{5}$ cm it's location is fixed.

Comment: @IONELABUCIU, What  does the the location have to do with the volume of tetrahedron? Isn't your question in fact  : find the location of point P?

Comment: @sirous -- Fact is, if you allege an XY problem makes obvious you did not solve the exercise on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the midpoint of A and B to M, the point where the line perpendicular to surface AXY and goes through P meets surface AXY to H.
Since PA=PB=PX=PY , A,B,Y and X are vertices of the pyramid P is the circumscribed sphere.

Since PB=PA ∠PMB=90

PM = √(BP^2-BM^2)=2

Since ∠BAX = ∠BAY= 90 and X,Y and H share the safe surface ∠BAH = 90

Therefore AB∥PH and PM∥AH so PM = AH = 2

Since AB∥PH , P is centre of sphere and H is in the same surface as A,X,Y
H is the centre of the circumcircle of △AXY .

Therefore AH = XH = YH = 2

Since AX=AY=2 △AXH and △AYH are regular triangles.

Therefore ∠XAH and ∠YAH = 60 and ∠XAY = 120

Therefor XY = 2√3 and △AXY =√3
Therefor volume of pyramid = △AXY*AB *1/3 =2√3/3
I think this is much simple then using sin like others.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Andy thank you so much for your answer! May I ask why H is the centre of the circumcircle of △AXY?

Comment: Moment please -- we get the same volume by different shaped $AXY$? In my approach $AXY$ is equilateral while in yours $AXH$ and $AYH$ are regurlar triangles. _Houston, we have a problem,_

Comment: Ok, my reasoning was wrong. Resulting equilateral $AXY$ had same area, thus the volume was same. But $AXY$ is _not_ equilateral.

Comment: to IONELA . The clean explanation is that , PH is the axis of symmetry. But there is another approach.  let the intersection point of BM and the sphere Q. From the inverse of the inscribed angle theorem ,   ∠BAQ = 90 because BQ is diameter. Since  ∠BAQ =  ∠BAM  and from symmetry AQ is same as AM. Also from symmetry AQ is the diameter of the circumcircle.  AQ =  √AB*AB+BQ*BQ=4. Since H is on AQ  and AH =2 which is half of diameter AQ ,H is the centre.  Sorry for the long proof  but I hope you get it . Also pls vote this answer useful . I want to start voting too. thx for the great math problem!

Answer (score 1):

From symmetry, point $P$ lies on the intersection of the perpendicular bisecting plane of $AB$, and the perpendicular bisecting plane of $XY$ as well as the perpendicular bisecting plane of $AX$.

Now let the base of the tetrahedron $\triangle AXY$ be in the $xy$ plane, with

$ A = (0,0,0), X = (2, 0, 0) , Y = (2 \cos(2\theta) , 2 \sin(2 \theta), 0) $ and finally $B = (0, 0, 2) $

The perpendicular bisecting plane of $AB$ has the equation $z = 1$, and the perpendicular bisecting plane of $XY$ has the equation $ - \sin(\theta) x + \cos \theta y = 0 $.  Finally, the bisecting plane of $AX$ has the equation $x = 1$.  Therefore, point $P$ is given by

$P = (x, y, z) = (1, y , 1 ) $

with $ 0 = - \sin \theta + \cos \theta \ y $, i.e.

$y = \tan \theta$

Since $P$ is $\sqrt{5}$ away from $A$ which is at the origin, then

$ 2 + y^2 = 5 $

Therefore,  $ y = \sqrt{3} $

And $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3} $

Therefore, the volume of the tetrahedron is

$ V = \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} (2)^2 \sin(2 \theta) (2) = \dfrac{4}{3} \sin( \dfrac{2 \pi}{3} ) = \dfrac{2 \sqrt{3}}{3} $